# Subsestting Data Frames in R

Tags: r

I'm a beginner in Python/R and started applying it at my workplace. Now I'm trying to solve a little issue that I have.

The task: 
I have to download a .csv file (separated by semicolon) and import that file into excel, sort for the newly updated sites (there is a column, W, that has the title Update). From the updated sites create two new excel files: one for European sites, the other for non-european sites.

My initial thought process was this:

- list of EU countries (shortest list)
- separate sites which need update <- Update_sites
- separate Update_sites into EU and non-EU sites
- write EU and non-EU sites to independent excel files.

I managed to get it to work when in the update column or section it says "New":

```
install.packages("openxlsx")
library("openxlsx")
European_countries <- c("Andorra","Austria","Belarus","Belgium","Bosnia and Herzegovina","Bulgaria","Croatia","Czech Republic","Denmark","Estonia","Finland","France","Germany","Greece","Hungary","Iceland","Ireland","Italy","Latvia","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Malta","Moldova","Monaco","Montenegro","Netherlands","Norway","Poland","Portugal","Romania","Russia","San Marino","Serbia","Slovakia","Slovenia","Spain","Sweden","Switzerland","Ukraine","United Kingdom")

origin <- choose.files()

MyData <- read.csv(origin, sep = ";", header = TRUE,) 

Update_sites <- subset(MyData, Update == "Updated") 

EU_site <- Update_sites[Update_sites$Country %in% European_countries,]

'%ni%' <- Negate('%in%')

Not_EU_site <- Update_sites[Update_sites$Country %ni% European_countries,]

write.xlsx(EU_site, "C:/Users/WalzthE/Downloads/European_sites.xlsx") 
write.xlsx(Not_EU_site, "C:/Users/WalzthE/Downloads/Not_european_sites")
```

My problem comes however in the next scenarios:

1. When the update column values differ from new, or yes. Sometimes they are filled with "Updated/cellphone/sitemanager/locals" OR "New/manager" or "Updated /fax". I want to subset the cell just by having a content. 
   I was looking through the forums and found something like:

   ```
   z <- character(0)
   subset(df, !(rownmaes(df) %in% z))
   ```

   but this didn't help me...
2. I want to be able to chose where to save the files instead of saving to a predetermined folder. This isn't as important as point 1, just to give more options to the users.
3. There is specific data in the csv file, such as "Study No. XYXY" and "LOL-123" these two make up the name of the file at the end when I need to save it, how can i concatenate both of these such that the final file name would be : "Study No.XYXY_LOL-123"

Thank you in advance, any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would begin by writing a script without `choose.files` type interaction. Something like this:

```
input_file <- "file.txt"
output_eu <- "eu.xlsx"
output_noteu <- "noteu.xlsx"

url <- "http://????"
download.file(url, "file.txt")

eu <- c("Andorra","Austria","Belarus","Belgium","Bosnia and Herzegovina","Bulgaria","Croatia","Czech Republic","Denmark","Estonia","Finland","France","Germany","Greece","Hungary","Iceland","Ireland","Italy","Latvia","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Malta","Moldova","Monaco","Montenegro","Netherlands","Norway","Poland","Portugal","Romania","Russia","San Marino","Serbia","Slovakia","Slovenia","Spain","Sweden","Switzerland","Ukraine","United Kingdom")

d <- read.table(input_file, sep = ";", header = TRUE) 
# get all cases where there is some text in the Update field
updates <- d[d$Update != "", ]
i <- updates$Country %in% eu
eu_up <- update[i,]
noteu_up <- update[!i,]

library(writexl)
write_xlsx(eu_up, output_eu) 
write_xlsx(noteu_up, output_noteu)
```

(also, there is no such thing as a `.csv file separated by semicolon`; the `c` stands for comma)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much! oh yeah my bad! I wanted to specify that the separator being used was a semicolon! Thank you once again Robert, great code!

Comment: If Robert answered your question, please accept the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers